# Magento - Changing the place of block to another page

Tags: xml, magento, templates, layout, themes

I am using MA2 Juno theme and trying to move default checkout block to another place.

Like this

Before : http://i42.tinypic.com/2ptw8ps.png
After: http://i42.tinypic.com/oausdw.png

For this i figured out that i have to move this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topBlock1') ?>
```

code block from header.phtml to topMenu.phtml

But after i changed, it didn't worked. I think i need to tell somehow to magento that topBlock1.phtml is ChildHtml of topMenu.phtml. But i didn't know how.

After a very long Google search i saw that i have to something in local.xml file.

I did something like this but it didn't work. Can you guys help me ?

```
<reference name="topMenu">
        <block name="top.block1" template="page/html/topBlock1.phtml" type="page/html_topblock1" as="topBlock1">
          <label>Top1 blocks</label>
        </block>
</reference>
```

PS: CSS file changes are not important i know how to edit those and override.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in local.xml file

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                    <block name="top.block1" template="page/html/topBlock1.phtml" type="page/html_topblock1" as="topBlock1">
                        <label>Top1 blocks</label>
                    </block>
                 </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </default>  
</layout>
```

Comment: @Semih Masat let me know if this is working for you.

Comment: i pasted the code like
<layout> yourcode </layout> but it didn't worked.

Comment: Layout inside layout ? like this  : http://i41.tinypic.com/33ory4n.png PS: Doesn't worked.

Comment: no no not layout inside layout.their will be one layout on first line and their will be one layout closed at the end. on the second line paste this default code

Comment: btw, can you re send your first suggestion again ?